# X, Y coordinates in thousands to millions

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a shapefile of contour lines and the X and Y coordinates are in thousands not in millions. How can I transform them in millions?

Like:

```
7802,305 to 7802305,00.
```

Comment: This is a good reason why Esri shouldn't have removed ability to calculate the geometry field from the field calculator (at 8.3?).

Answer (score 2):

This is the same suggestion as Andre Joost's but for ArcGIS. It assumes that the data currently doesn't have a defined coordinate system but that you know what the data is georeferenced to (ex. It's in UTM but with units of kilometers).

Modify it to use "Kilometer" for the units of the projected coordinate system. The false easting and northing values (if any) should update. To stay with the UTM example, a Northern hemisphere zone has a false easting of 500000m. That value will change to 500km.

Use the Project tool to create a new shapefile using the same coordinate system, but with units set to "Meter" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Arcgis, but in GDAL/QGIS you can set up custom projections with kilometres as units. Maybe it is already sufficient to change that in the .prj file.

Answer (score -1):

there should be a false easting and false northing on your projection. find a projection "without" false EN

Comment: Changing the false easting and northing will *shift* the coordinates but not rescale them as requested in the question.

Comment: where did the question say rescale? (the word transform) I was hoping OP would clarify. is he not using decimal? is he using intl decimal? does he want 8 decimals instead of 3? Am I not correct if he doesn't want the objects to move he would need to re-project from a false easting projection to one without false easting?

Comment: "Like, 7802,305 to 7802305,00" describes a rescaling by a factor of 1000 (understanding the European convention of using a comma as a decimal point). Asking to change "thousands" to "millions" is also consistent with rescaling by 1000.  If you are looking for clarification, then please use the comment facility for that.